# Plugin constructor called multiple times

Tags: plugins, ajax, hooks

I have plugin with the following structure -

```
class emailPlg {        
    static $tableName;    
    static $pluginDbVersion = 1.0;   

    function __construct() {
        global $wpdb;
        emailPlg::$tableName = $wpdb->prefix . 'emails';
        $installedPluginVer = get_site_option(EMAIL_VER);
        if ($installedPluginVer != cases::$pluginDbVersion) {
            $this->buildDb();        
        }            
        add_action('wp_ajax_emailsActionTag', array($this,'handleRequests'));
        add_action('wp_ajax_nopriv_emailsActionTag', array($this,'handleRequests'));
        add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', array($this,'enqueScripts'));
    }

    function buildDb() {   
    }

    function handleRequests() {
        $recvData = $_POST['dataToProcess'];
        $respData = call_user_func(array($this, $recvData['method']), $recvData['data']);
        ob_clean();
        echo json_encode($respData);
        die();
    }           

    function enqueScripts() {
        wp_enqueue_script('emails-js', plugins_url('/js/email.js', __FILE__), array('jquery'));        
    }
}
add_action('plugins_loaded', 'loadEmails');

function loadEmails() {
    new emailPlg();
}
```

While debugging in Netbeans with xDebux, I noticed that the `class constructor` and `loadEmails` is getting called multiple times. Is this normal? *I'm calling this plugin through ajax*. Does `call_user_func` call the constructor everytime?

I am making multiple `AJAX` calls to different plugins, could that be causing this?

Comment: From where exactly is it being called?

Comment: From a jQuery file. I am making multiple `AJAX` calls to different plugins, could that be causing this?

Comment: if you use a debuger then it should be trivial to have a stack trace and see what calls it